# Java API to use for queries based on maxTimeuuid and minTimeuuid

Tags: java, cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

What is the Java API for using maxTimeuuid and minTimeuuid based queries? I could not find any in the QueryBuilder or anywhere else. I am using DataStax client

```
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
```

Table "a" has 2 columns:
1. id of type String
2. LMD of type TimeUuid

This is what I am doing and does not seem right and of course does not work

```
    Query q = QueryBuilder
    .select()
    .all()
    .from("test","a")
    .where().and(QueryBuilder.gt("LMD", "minTimeUUid('2013-11-03 14:33:50')"))
    .and(QueryBuilder.lt("LMD", "maxTimeUUId('2013-11-03 14:45:50')"));
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You will need to generate the max/min TimeUUIDs programatically, from timestamps using the [utils.UUIDs](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/1.0/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html) utility class, e.g.

```
final UUID min = UUIDs.startOf(lowerTimeStamp);
final UUID max = UUIDs.endOf(upperTimeStamp);
Query q = QueryBuilder
  .select()
  .all()
  .from("test","a")
  .where(QueryBuilder.gt("LMD", min))
  .and(QueryBuilder.lt("LMD", max));
```

Comment: Thanks lorcan for the insight. The query will not work as is. Do you happen to know how we can add "allow filtering" using the java api? I know this is part of Select class but based on QueryBuilder...how can do it?

Comment: I edited it slightly (removed the empty `where` call). Do you have any more info on the error?

Comment: Yes: Here is the error when I execute it as as: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

Comment: Ah, you need to include your primary key - could you paste the table definition into your question?

Comment: @Masti, try calling `allowFiltering()` before the call to `where()`

Answer (score 2):

For later versions of the datastax java driver you can use the `QueryBuilder.fcall` like (here I assume static import of QueryBuilder.*):

```
Query q = select()
  .all()
  .from("test","a")
  .where(gt("LMD", fcall("minTimeUuid", lowerTimeStamp)))
  .and(lt("LMD", fcall("minTimeUuid", upperTimeStamp)));
```

But it is important to use fcall it with the correct data type for the second argument (`long` in this case).

V4 of the driver even have `QueryBuilder.minTimeUuid()` and `QueryBuilder.maxTimeUuid()` methods